# Why splash screen for mobile app is square?

Tags: mobile, splash-screen

In most [splash screen generators](http://apetools.webprofusion.com/tools/imagegorilla), they require a square picture. Splash screens are shown on the entire phone height and phone screens aren't squares. So why do they ask for square images?

Comment: It is not the ideal requirement. The website you have mentioned requires it to be measuring 2048x2048 pixels, with the important stuff centred, as they will then crop and resize from the centre outwards.

Answer (score 0):

The sample you provided (and many others out there in the web) is/are primarily a icon generator and only on the second sight splashscreeen generator(s).

Due to this and the fact that nearly all icons in the world used in app-stores and mobile-os vegetation are square they specialized on square icon generation.

As a consequence you upload a square picture in order to create all the square icons. The splash screen is then only an exception to this.

If they wouldn't take the same picture for the splash screen, the sites would force you to provide a second image just for the splash screen creation process. This would make the site unintuitive and would decrease user friendliness, because you either don't want the splash screen to have a different look or you would have to choose the same image twice.